# Freemarker - Check Boolean value

Tags: java, boolean, freemarker

What's the right syntax to check if the value of boolean from the form data in FreeMarker, my code:

```
<#if "${form.allStores}" !false>
        <@displayRow label="Receiving Stores" value="All Stores" />
    <#elseif "${form.storesReceiving}" == false || "${form.storesReceiving}"?has_content>
        <@displayRow label="Receiving Stores" value="No Stores"/>
    <#else>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Could not prepare mail; nested exception is freemarker.core._MiscTemplateException: Can't convert boolean to string automatically, because the "boolean_format" setting was "true,false", which is the legacy default computer-language format, and hence isn't accepted. --
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Freemarker has [then function](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_boolean.html#ref_builtin_then) since version 2.3.23:

```
<@displayRow label="Receiving Stores" value="${form.allStores?then('All Stores', 'No Stores')}"/>
```

> Used like booleanExp?then(whenTrue, whenFalse)

Also similar to java, you can use the [`!` operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators) to negate:

```
<#if !form.allStores> 
    <@displayRow label="Receiving Stores" value="No Stores"/>
```

Then boolean can be only true/false so don't need `elseif` :

```
<#else>
    <@displayRow label="Receiving Stores" value="All Stores" />
</#if>
```

> Called Logical NOT Operator. Use to reverses the logical state of its operand. If a condition is true then Logical NOT operator will make false.

Also prefer to use first positive condition as:

```
<#if form.allStores> 
    <@displayRow label="Receiving Stores" value="All Stores" />
<#else>
    <@displayRow label="Receiving Stores" value="No Stores"/>
</#if>
```